# typo3: realurl extension- configuration issue, include path-fragment in url

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, realurl

Assume I have a website www.mywebsite.com. My typo3 v4.7 frontend is located at, say,

```
www.mywebsite.com/cms/index.php
```

, and the backend is located at www.mywebsite.com/cms/typo3/.

How do I configure  the "friendly" urls, that the realurl extension generates, in a way that urls are mapped as follows:

```
www.mywebsite.com/cms/index.php?id=45
```

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/cms/something
```

I want to use the autoconfiguration feature of realurl.

This is how the autoconfig file looks like:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
  '_DEFAULT' => 
  array (
    'init' => 
    array (
      'enableCHashCache' => true,
      'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
      'adminJumpToBackend' => true,
      'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
      'enableUrlEncodeCache' => true,
      'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/cms/',
    ),
    'pagePath' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'user',
      'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
      'spaceCharacter' => '-',
      'languageGetVar' => 'L',
      'rootpage_id' => '13',
    ),
    'fileName' => 
    array (
      'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
      'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
      'index' => 
      array (
        'print' => 
        array (
          'keyValues' => 
          array (
            'type' => 98,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
?>
```

I can't get it done. There are more virtual hosts on this website. I don't want to build a new dedicated virtual host just for this typ3 installation.

Currently, redirects do not work. There is a generic with a  "Page ... was not found on this server." error-message issued by Apache.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine on
        #RewriteBase /cms/
       RewriteRule ^/cms/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)(/.*)?$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has currently nothing to do with RealURL and its configuration. You have a problem with mod_rewrite configuration. Start with the original one that is shipped with TYPO3 because the bit you posted is missing crucial rules. Try to set the `RewriteBase` but if it doesn't work, disable it.

Note that it's actually the last rule (`RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`) that invokes TYPO3 and makes it handle the request, which apparently doesn't happen right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
RewriteBase /cms/

# Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Redirect http://example.com/typo3 to http://example.com/typo3/index_re.php and stop the rewrite processing.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/typo3$ /TYPO3root/typo3/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Main URL rewriting.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule .* /TYPO3root/index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: instead using TYPO3 in subfolder it's much more comfortable to put it into subdomain like `cms.mydomain.com`. In such case you don't need an additional re-configuration, and all elements works as it was normal domain.